# Electron bluetooth communication to mobile app

Tags: electron, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to connect my electron app to an iOS/Android app (which doesn't exist yet) via Bluetooth to transfer data. The reason is that the network that the electron app exists on usually does not have an internet connection. What I'd like to do is connect the electron app to the iOS/Android app so that I can use the phone's cell connection to send the data out to my server. It's a pretty unique scenario so I'm happy to provide more information if necessary. But I'm hoping someone here has an idea of how to get me started with using Bluetooth to transmit data between an electron app and a (react-native/ionic?) app. Any ideas?